# Squid proxy server configuration issue with Instagram media content

Tags: ubuntu, squid

I am trying to configure a squid proxy on the remote virtual server in order to access blocked content from my smartphone.
I have installed Squid and everything works, but for some reason Instagram media content is not loading. Instagram itself works, but only text. Again, other sites and social networks work fine, for instance Facebook or Linkedin.

What can be the problem? Why exactly  instagram's media content does not work properly?
My simple config below. I've tried 3proxy - same result, IG media content doesn't load.

When I connect via SSH tunnel via same server or via OpenVPN which is installed on the same remote server and don't use proxy in this case, all works fine. Therefore, something wrong with squid configuration.

When I try to open instagram.com on PC via my proxy, site totally doesn't open.  ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS occurred.

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 3129
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
```